# How do scalar variables perform in memory?

Tags: perl

In other languages besides Perl when you declare an integer it has minimum and maximum values based on the amount of space in memory the variable is taking up.
When you declare a scalar variable in Perl, whether it be a number or string, does the language only allocate enough for the variable value and then increase the space if necessary later or does Perl allocate a large amount of memory initially?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Perl, a scalar variable is a pointer to a C struct called an `SV`. This includes various fields for metadata like the reference count, a bitfield that determines the exact type, and a pointer to additional (meta-)data.

- If you use a scalar as an integer, it is called an `IV` and contains an integer. The size of this integer is fixed at compilation of `perl`. You can look at the `perl -V` output to view the size of various data types. I have `ivsize=8`. The representable values are the same as for the C integer of that size.
- If you use a scalar as a decimal, it is called an `NV` (numerical value) and contains a double, usually. Again, the exact size is determined at compile time.
- If you use a scalar as a string, it is called a `PV` and contains a pointer to a C string, plus some additional metadata like length. The C string is reallocated if it grows.
- If you use a scalar as a string and as a number, it is a `PVIV` or `PVNV` resp. and includes the data of both types.
- There are additional types like references (`RV`) or unsigned integers (`UV`).

For the `IV` and `NV`, Perl does not automatically promote the numbers to bignums when they grow large enough.

Then there are hashes `HV` and arrays `AV`. These use the `SV` header for things like reference counting but point to more complicated data structures.

- Arrays contain a C array of pointers to `SV`s. If the array grows, it is reallocated.
- Hashes are far more complex. Basically, they are an array as well, but contain hash entries instead of `SV`s. The elements in this hash are called *buckets*. If the entries-to-buckets ratio is too high, the array is reallocated (usually to double size) and the entries newly distributed across these buckets. This isn't strictly neccessary, but if this isn't done then lookup is `O(n)` instead of `O(1)` (i.e. *slow*).

---

- Variable sized data structures like strings, arrays, hashes are initially allocated conservatively. If more space is required, then a larger piece of memory is allocated, and the data copied over.
- Scalars have a constant-sized header. Additional memory for additional metadata is allocated when the type changes (e.g. through stringification).

For more information and confusing pointer diagrams read the [Illustrated Perl Guts](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.42/index-14.html).